# Reading of Chinese Name

Tags: names, reading

Could someone help with a reading of this name please:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This signature is 冯群 feng2 qun2

You can get the pronunciation in Google Translation, Choose Chinese

Comment: thank you for your help!